# How to access the JQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

How do I access the jquery object when validateName is called?

In my code below, `errorDate` is not a JQuery object.

**Correction to variable name**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var errorDate = $("#errorDate");
    errorDate.blur(validateName);

    function validateName() {
        if (errorDate.val().length == "") {
            errorDate.addClass("error");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            errorDate.removeClass("error");
            return true;
        }
    }  
});
```

Comment: Apologies, my mistake. Variable name corrected as also mentioned in your post. Thanks @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var errorDate = $("#errorDate");
    errorDate.blur(validateName);

    function validateName() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val().length == "") {
            $this.addClass("error");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $this.removeClass("error");
            return true;
        }
    }  
});
```

Or use `errorDate` instead of `name` since it is a closure variable

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var errorDate = $("#errorDate");
    errorDate.blur(validateName);

    function validateName() {
        if (errorDate.val().length == "") {
            errorDate.addClass("error");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            errorDate.removeClass("error");
            return true;
        }
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use `$(this)` instead of `name`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var errorDate = $("#errorDate");
    errorDate.blur(validateName);

    function validateName() {
        // no need to get length you can use $(this).val()==""
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).addClass("error");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("error");
            return true;
        }
    }  
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jtWFX/